# pdfbookmark does not work with special characters

Tags: labels, bookmarks

I'm writing a document in English, but I also have some parts in other language.

I created my own style to change how the `book` class behaves, which also includes headings for `chapter` and `chapter*` environments. As part of this, in definition for `chapter*` I added the `pdfbookmark` command, so that all unnumbered chapters appear in the bookmark. Here is the definition:

```
\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
    {%
        \pdfbookmark[0]{#1}{#1}%
        \vspace*{\@spacebeforechapterhead}%
        \parindent 0pt \Large%\bfseries
        \interlinepenalty\@M%
        \vspace*{\@spaceinchapterhead}%
        \rule{0.666\textwidth}{0.5pt}%
        \par%
        \vspace*{\@spaceinchapterhead}%
        \vspace*{\@spaceinchapterhead}%
        {\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}\hfill}%
        \mbox{}\par%
        \mbox{}\par%
        \mbox{}\par%
        \markright{}%remove header, there were problems with "My publications" header after "Bibliography"
    }%
}
```

Everything works as I expected, except unnumbered chapters that contain special characters in their name, for example

```
\chapter*{Sa{ž}etak}
```

The problem here is with the third argument in the `pdfbookmark` command, which is something like a label for the bookmark. I tried attacking this problem from different angles, but nothing seems to work. Simple solution would be to remove the `pdfbookmark` command from the `chapter*` definition, and to add it manually for all unnumbered chapters, but I'm trying to find a more elegant solution.

One of the possible solutions that I haven't tried is to put something like

```
\RemoveAllNonASCII{#1}
```

as the third argument, but I don't know how to design a function like that.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

---

Here is the minimum working example:

**mwe.tex**

```
\documentclass{style}

\begin{document}

\author{Me}
\title{MWE}

\maketitle

% Bookmark works
\chapter*{Unnumbered chapter}

% Bookmark does not work
\chapter*{Unnumbered chapter Ž}

% Bookmark works
\chapter{Numbered chapter}

% Bookmarks works, even though we have Ž in the title
\chapter{Numbered chapter Ž}

\end{document}
```

**style.cls**

```
\LoadClass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
    {%
        \pdfbookmark[0]{#1}{#1}%
        {#1}
    }%
}
```

Comment: What happens if you add an optional parameter to your \chapter*? ```\chapter*[Sazetak]{Sa{ž}etak}```?

Comment: Thank you for your inputs, unfortunately they did not work. I added minimum working example. However, Ulrike Fischer proposed a solution that works. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something sensible as third argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{myschapter}
\begin{document}
 abc
\stepcounter{myschapter}
\pdfbookmark[0]{Sa{ž}etak}{schapter.\number\value{myschapter}}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent idea, I've set `\thepage` as label for bookmarks (third argument in the `pdfbookmark` command), everything works fine now. Thank you!